# Persisting data in java with jaxb for a standalone program

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working on a hobby/learning project, and I need to persist some data, but I don't want to use a database. After some research, I found that using JAXB could be a good idea, but I can't seem to wrap my head around using it. I read tutorials, and the documentation as well, but it just doesn't click for me.

The program is a receipt storing/budgeting type of thing, so I'd need to save the receipts somehow.

The relevant classes look like this so far:

```
package classes;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Receipt {

    private String shop;
    private LocalDate date;
    private Double total;
    private List<Entry> items;

//...contructor,getters & setters
```

and

```
package classes;

public class Entry {

    private String name;
    private Double price;

//...contructor,getters & setters
```

And what I'd like to have looks kinda like this:

```
<Receipts>
    <Receipt>
        <Shop>Tesco</Shop>
        <Date>2016-06-03</Date>
        <Total>200</Total>
        <Items>
            <Item>foo 100</Item>
            <Item>bar 100</Item>
        </Items>
    </Receipt>
    ...
</Receipts>
```

So I guess, I have 2 questions:
1. Am I on the right track with JAXB, is it a right way of persisting data for a standalone application?
2. How can I do it? I don't understand all the annotations and schemas and stuff.

I'd appreciate any help, pointing me to a good tutorial, or writing a very didactic guide.

Thank you

Comment: JAXB isn't going to persist anything by itself, but it will provide you with tools to convert Java Objects into XML data (similar to what you've outlined). It would be up to you to write that data to files on your filesystem and then read them when you need them. This seems a serviceable guide for JAXB's api: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/  As for reading/writing files check out this (straight from oracle): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html particularly this section: Buffered I/O Methods for Text Files

Comment: (Rant: How I hate "persist" as a transitive verb. When the word "persistence" was introduced around 1990, the whole idea was that persistence was a declarative property of data, not a procedural action performed by programmers or programs.)

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is not is not a persistence engine. You can use it to convert XML to Java objects or objects to XML. The data can be persisted on files or even databases. JAXB does not replace a database. You have no searches, relationships between different entities, indexes, XML data is loaded entirely, etc.

If you want to use it in your learning project these are the main parts. I include only the annotations and changes to code to map your model

Java objects

```
//Added XmlRootElement and XmlElement for list
@XmlRootElement(name = "Receipts")
public class Receipts {
    private List<Receipt> receipts;

    @XmlElement(name = "Receipt")
    public List<Receipt> getReceipts() {


//Added XmlElementWrapper and XmlElement for list   
public class Receipt {

    private String shop;
    private Date date; //Changed to Date because marshalling is directly supported
    private Double total;
    private List<Entry> items ;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    public List<Entry> getItems() {

//No changes    
public class Entry {
    private String name;
    private Double price;
```

Marshall (Java to XML)

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Receipts.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(receipts, new File(file);
```

Unmarshaller (XML to Java)

```
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Receipts receiptsUnmarshalled = (Receipts) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```